# React/Flux + Jasmine - Expected spy to have been called fails

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, jasmine, flux

I'm not really sure why this happens, I have a very simple Component and test, however, it fails on `✖ should call getState on TestStore`. But as `getStateFromStores` DOES get called, it should be called as well, right? I am clueless atm.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import TestStore from '../stores/TestStore'

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
  }

  static getStateFromStores() {
    return TestStore.getState()
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = TestComponent.getStateFromStores()
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <img src='' alt=''/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Test:

```
var React = require('react')
var TestUtils = require('react/lib/ReactTestUtils')
var Immutable = require('immutable')

const mockTestStoreData = Immutable.fromJS({
  one: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  two: {
    bar: 'baz'
  }
})

describe('TestComponent.jsx', () => {

  var TestStore
  var TestComponent
  var TestComponentEl
  var renderedRootElement
  var renderedDOMNode

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestStore = require('../../stores/TestStore')
    spyOn(TestStore, 'getState') // .and.returnValue(mockTestStoreData)
    TestComponent = require('../TestComponent.jsx')
    spyOn(TestComponent, 'getStateFromStores')
    TestComponentEl = React.createElement(TestComponent)
    renderedRootElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(TestComponentEl)
    renderedDOMNode = React.findDOMNode(renderedRootElement)
  })

  it('should be rendered within a div', () => {
    expect(renderedDOMNode.tagName.toUpperCase()).toEqual('DIV')
  })

  it('should have a static getStateFromStores function', () => {
    expect(TestComponent.getStateFromStores).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('should call getStateFromStores on construction', () => {
    expect(TestComponent.getStateFromStores).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

  it('should call getState on TestStore', () => {
    expect(TestStore.getState).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

`TestStore.getState()` is supposed to be called from `TestComponent.getStateFromStores()`, but you are spying on `TestComponent.getStateFromStores()`:

```
...
spyOn(TestComponent, 'getStateFromStores');
...
```

so the actual implementation is not being invoked during your tests. To spy on a function and also have it called, you could change to:

```
spyOn(TestComponent, 'getStateFromStores').and.callThrough();
```

[Documentation for callThrough()](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_%3Ccode%3Eand.callThrough%3C/code%3E).

That being said, testing whether or not methods get called inside the module you are testing is perhaps too implementation specific. It's better to keep the test more cause-and-effect oriented. So my suggested solution would be to make the following **adjustments**:

```
var React = require('react')

    var TestUtils = require('react/lib/ReactTestUtils')
    var Immutable = require('immutable')

    const mockTestStoreData = Immutable.fromJS({
      one: {
        foo: 'bar'
      },
      two: {
        bar: 'baz'
      }
    })

    describe('TestComponent.jsx', () => {

      var TestStore
      var TestComponent
      var TestComponentEl
      var renderedRootElement
      var renderedDOMNode

      beforeEach(() => {
        TestStore = require('../../stores/TestStore')
        spyOn(TestStore, 'getState').and.returnValue(mockTestStoreData);
        TestComponent = require('../TestComponent.jsx')
        // don't spyOn(TestComponent, 'getStateFromStores')
        TestComponentEl = React.createElement(TestComponent)
        renderedRootElement = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(TestComponentEl)
        renderedDOMNode = React.findDOMNode(renderedRootElement)
      })

      it('should be rendered within a div', () => {
        expect(renderedDOMNode.tagName.toUpperCase()).toEqual('DIV')
      })

      it('should have a static getStateFromStores function', () => {
        expect(TestComponent.getStateFromStores).toBeDefined()
      })

      // don't
      //it('should call getStateFromStores on construction', () => {
      //  expect(TestComponent.getStateFromStores).toHaveBeenCalled()
      //})

      // don't
      //it('should call getState on TestStore', () => {
      //  expect(TestStore.getState).toHaveBeenCalled()
      //})

      // instead
      it( 'should get its initial state from TestStore', () => {
        expect(TestStore.getState).toHaveBeenCalled(); // I'd say optional
        expect( TestComponent.state ).toEqual( mockTestStoreData );
      })
    })
```

Now you're free to change the implementation and are testing what is important: the state of TestComponent after it is initialized.